# cURL ERROR: 0: NSS: client certificate not found

Tags: php, curl, soap

I'm trying to connect to a API using SOAP (nusoap client), but when i try and make a request I get this error:

```
wsdl error: Getting https://example.com/webservices.asmx?WSDL - HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 0: NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
```

The API does not require a certificate to connect to the API, but for some reason I am getting an error with a none existent certificate. This code works on my VM, but not on the live site, does anyone know why this error is occurring?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: It means it can't find it's SSL certificate.

Comment: the ssl certificate of the server? or the client?

Comment: your client certificate that the server is requesting for authentication